# String comparison if-statement used by Python

Tags: python, string, comparison

I understand(I've read about "The comparison uses lexicographical ordering") how "String comparison technique used by Python" works, but in line `if email.rfind('.') > email.find('@') + 1:` Im not able to figure out how and why it works. Dot `.` is 46, and `@` is 64.

```
print("a " + str(ord("a")))
print("b " + str(ord("b")))
print("c " + str(ord("c")))
print(". " + str(ord(".")))
print("@ " + str(ord("@")))

print('aab' < 'aac')
print()


def check_email(email):
    if " " not in email and "@" in email:
        if email.rfind('.') > email.find('@') + 1:
            return True
    return False


print(check_email("mailfff@x.uss"))
print(check_email("mailfff@xus.s"))
print(check_email("mailfff@xuss"))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a 97
b 98
c 99
. 46
@ 64
True

True
True
False
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). `rfind` is not `ord`. See what `rfind('.')` and `find('@')` return, you'll see why that evaluates to True.

Comment: `.rfind` has nothing to do with `ord`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi omg! thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `rfind` returns the position of character in the string not the ascii value like `ord`

```
>>> email = "mailfff@x.uss"
>>> email.rfind('.')
9
>>> email.rfind('@')
7
```

so `if email.rfind('.') > email.rfind('@')` returns `True`